# DQS failed to execute in the package SSIS 2012

Tags: sql, ssis, data-quality-services

I am new to used the SSIS! I'm trying to use the DQS within the package to apply the business role on a specific column in the source table i.e. Contact title. This column takes different job titles related to Sales people, matching the values on the domain to the existed data. I made a package to perform this, inserting data from the source into the staging, but an error  is propagated on the DQS part whenever I run the package.

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: DQS Cleansing through Insert failed validation
>   and returned error code 0x80131516.

[image]

[image]

I hope someone can help / guide me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and reading many sources, I have found the solution for this kind of problems. The solution is hidden behind the reason! I simply changed the driver from default and the package was good to go. Steps to solve the issue are the following for future reference:

**Step 1:** Navigate to Project -> [PROJECT_NAME] Properties.

**Step 2:** Navigate to “Debugging” option from left panel and from Right panel, change Run64BitRuntime value to false.